# How to force gcc to find its own c++ header files, without overriding CXX variable?

Tags: c++, gcc, header, compiler-errors, include

I recently compiled gcc from source:

```
CC="gcc -g -O3 -msse3 -pipe -isystem /usr/include -m64" \
CXX="g++ -g -O3 -msse3 -pipe -isystem /usr/include -m64" \
LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/lib64:/lib64:/usr/lib32:/lib32" \
  ../gcc-4.8.2/configure \
    --prefix=/usr \
    --libdir=/usr/lib64 \
    --libexecdir=/usr/lib64 \
    --enable-shared \
    --enable-threads=posix \
    --enable-__cxa_atexit \
    --enable-c99 \
    --enable-long-long \
    --enable-clocale=gnu \
    --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,java,objc,obj-c++ \
    --disable-libstdcxx-pch \
    --enable-cloog-backend=isl \
    --disable-isl-version-check \
    --with-system-zlib \
    --enable-checking=release \
    --enable-libstdcxx-time \
    --enable-lto \
    --with-cpu32=generic \
    --with-cpu64=generic \
    --with-tune32=generic \
    --with-tune64=generic \
    --disable-install-libiberty
make -j1 profiledbootstrap
make install
```

but after installation the new c++ compiler does not want to find its very own include files, however they are installed under:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/
```

I can fix this behaviour by overriding the default CXX variable

```
CXX="c++ -I/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/" \
./configure
make
make install
```

This is weird, because before I installed my own gcc, the previous one did find the include files without the need to override CXX.

Is there a way to force gcc to find the include files without overriding CXX?

Consider the package flac for example. With the old compiler I could compile the package by issuing the following commands:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr \
    --disable-thorough-tests
make
make install
```

However with the new compiler I have to issue the commands:

```
CXX="c++ -I/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/" \
./configure --prefix=/usr \
    --disable-thorough-tests
make
make install
```

Comment: Just to ask the obvious, you are compiling with g++ and not gcc?

Comment: Is that a problem? I mean if I change the above from g++ to gcc it will work?

Comment: no it is not a problem for C code, but g++ tacks on locations for the headers and runtime support for the standard library by default that are not there with just gcc when using certian file extensions.

Comment: _overriding the default CXXFLAGS variable_ For which build system in particular? You might still have the 4.7 toolchain specified for a particular build environment (e.g. CMake). I've recently had some problems to get the Eclipse CDT IDE getting the settings right for a newly installed (as default) GCC toolchain, BTW.

Comment: You're right, I have this problem only when I try to compile a package which is written in c++. I do not have this problem when using the C compiler.

Comment: I added an example to the question.

Comment: `CXX="c++ -I/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/"` looks strange indeed, if `gcc`(`g++`/`c++`) really defaults to the (correctly) installed 4.8 version the `-I` option should be intrinsic. Did you call `make install` with correct admin rights (`sudo`)? Check the actual symlinks for `/usr/bin/gcc' and `/usr/bin/local/gcc'. et. al., and what your `PATH` variable actually contains.

Comment: I always compile and install the packages as root, because I'm working in a chroot environment. My PATH variable is `/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin` the compiler installed in `/usr/bin` so `/usr/bin/gcc` is not a symlink, but the actual compiler itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to track down the problem: a wrong symlink. So it wasn't gcc's fault.

Comment: So that other people will be helped by this, could you provide more details? At the very least, which symlink needed to be fixed.